# Selenium WebDriver: How to install the firefox extension "Firefox WebDriver"?

Tags: firefox, selenium, firefox-addon, webdriver, browser-automation

I set up a browser automation project using Selenium WebDriver. It works just fine. When I try to run it on an other machine, though, it opens the browser (Firefox), but that's it, no automation. When timed out, it throws an error: `"Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms. Attempted to connect to the following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055"`. 7055 is the default port the firefox driver attempts to use for communication (see [this article](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriverInternals)).

On my machine, where everything works, Firefox has an extension installed called "Firefox WebDriver 2.42.0". When I type 127.0.0.1:7055 into the browser, it opens a page titled "httpd.js". I suppose it is served by the extension, because on the other machine it's not opening.

I was unable to find the extension in the web for download, and I was unable to understand where it comes from - it apears to not be installed manually.

Please help.

edit: reworded the question

Comment: Can you help with the complete error message?

Comment: Not at the moment, but soon. It said it tried to connect to 127.0.0.1:7055 but failed. When i navigate to that address on my own machine, it finds httpd.js, wich says its up and running. the other machine finds nothing. i suppose its the missing extension. i found this https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriverInternals, but it didnt help me to solve the issue. i just need to install the addon. the exact errormessage may not be of great use, but i gonna post it here asap.

Comment: Error message: "Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms. Attempted to connect to the following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055"

Comment: i reworded the question, for i need an answer, and no more downvotes :(

Comment: Good effort to try to get some help. Im not a selenium guy but hope someone can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. I was trying to run selenium 2.42.0 with firefox 38, wich is not supported. i updated both firefox and selenium and now everything works just fine again! :)

See [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp) for more details about compability.